# Xamarin iOS SIGABRT Crash On Startup

Tags: c#, xamarin, xamarin.ios

I've created a cross platform app using Xamarin. The Android version works great, but the IOS version crashes for maybe half of the users on app launch. I'm using AppCenter for error reporting but its giving cryptic reports. How can I decrypt this message and figure out why my app is crashing for seemingly no reason? I'm unable to get it to crash on the Simulator, and don't have access to the phones its crashing on.

```
Thread 0 Crashed:
0   libsystem_kernel.dylib               0x000000018d3c6930 __abort_with_payload + 8
1   libsystem_kernel.dylib               0x000000018d3caec0 abort_with_reason + 24
2   libobjc.A.dylib                      0x000000018d314244 _objc_fatalv(unsigned long long, unsigned long long, char const*, char*) + 100
3   libobjc.A.dylib                      0x000000018d3141dc _objc_fatal(char const*, ...) + 24
4   libobjc.A.dylib                      0x000000018d3114a8 void AutoreleasePoolPage::busted<void (*)(char const*, ...)>(void (*)(char const*, ...)) const + 144
5   libobjc.A.dylib                      0x000000018d314a6c AutoreleasePoolPage::busted_die() const + 8
6   libobjc.A.dylib                      0x000000018d313520 objc_autoreleasePoolPop + 52
7   CoreFoundation                       0x000000018d5dcd40 _CFAutoreleasePoolPop + 24
8   UIKitCore                            0x000000019164f4dc _prepareForCAFlush + 116
9   UIKitCore                            0x000000019167f770 _afterCACommitHandler + 116
10  CoreFoundation                       0x000000018d54de68 __CFRUNLOOP_IS_CALLING_OUT_TO_AN_OBSERVER_CALLBACK_FUNCTION__ + 28
11  CoreFoundation                       0x000000018d548d54 __CFRunLoopDoObservers + 412
12  CoreFoundation                       0x000000018d549320 __CFRunLoopRun + 1304
13  CoreFoundation                       0x000000018d548adc CFRunLoopRunSpecific + 460
14  GraphicsServices                     0x00000001974e9328 GSEventRunModal + 100
15  UIKitCore                            0x000000019165663c UIApplicationMain + 1932
16  MyApp.iOS                            0x00000001018c5330 0x100a04000 + 15471408
17  MyApp.iOS                            0x000000010182376c 0x100a04000 + 14808940
18  MyApp.iOS                            0x00000001018236f4 0x100a04000 + 14808820
19  MyApp.iOS                            0x0000000100a8dc24 0x100a04000 + 564260
20  MyApp.iOS                            0x0000000100de3404 0x100a04000 + 4060164
21  MyApp.iOS                            0x0000000101ff1d08 0x100a04000 + 22994184
22  MyApp.iOS                            0x00000001020afa00 0x100a04000 + 23771648
23  MyApp.iOS                            0x00000001020b5cbc 0x100a04000 + 23796924
24  MyApp.iOS                            0x0000000101fcfc9c 0x100a04000 + 22854812
25  MyApp.iOS                            0x0000000102191f2c 0x100a04000 + 24698668
26  MyApp.iOS                            0x0000000100a8db7c 0x100a04000 + 564092
27  libdyld.dylib                        0x000000018d3d2360 start + 0
```

---

AppDelegate.cs

```
[Register("AppDelegate")]
public partial class AppDelegate : global::Xamarin.Forms.Platform.iOS.FormsApplicationDelegate
{
    public override bool FinishedLaunching(UIApplication app, NSDictionary options)
    {
        AppCenter.Start("my-secret", typeof(Analytics), typeof(Crashes));

        App.screenWidth = (int)UIScreen.MainScreen.Bounds.Width;
        App.screenHeight = (int)UIScreen.MainScreen.Bounds.Height;

        CrossMediaManager.Current.Init();

        HtmlLabelRenderer.Initialize();
        Forms.SetFlags("CarouselView_Experimental");

        global::Xamarin.Forms.Forms.Init();

        LoadApplication(new App());
        return base.FinishedLaunching(app, options);
    }
}
```

---

Main.cs

```
static void Main(string[] args) {
    try {
        UIApplication.Main(args, null, "AppDelegate");
    }
    catch (Exception e) {
        Globals.ReportError(e, "Main.cs", "Main", "Crash");
    }
}
```

(Globals.ReportError is just a helper for AppCenter reporting.)

Comment: Have you added all the UDIDs with provisioning profile?

Comment: did you added all the permissions on info.plist, sometimes this happens when you are using something that need permission and you have not added.

Answer (score 2):

The information you provided is not enough to figure out what is wrong. I have a suggestion on how to figure out the issue. It's not an answer but it would be too long to place in a comment. Place this after your AppCenter start:

```
if (Crashes.HasCrashedInLastSessionAsync().Result)
{
    ErrorReport crashReport = Crashes.GetLastSessionCrashReportAsync().Result;
    if (crashReport.Exception == null)
        Analytics.TrackEvent("AppCrashedInLastLaunch: Crash Report Exception is Null");
    else
    {
        Crashes.TrackError(crashReport.Exception);
        var dict = new Dictionary<string, string>();
        dict.Add("CrashId", crashReport.Id);
        dict.Add("StackTrace", crashReport.Exception.StackTrace);
        Analytics.TrackEvent(string.Format("AppCrashedInLastLaunch: " + crashReport.Exception.Message), dict);
    }
}
```

Alternatively, you can share the Testflight public link and I can help you test!

Comment: Ok! I will give this a try on the next release! Thanks!

Comment: @bwoogie what was the bug

Comment: @bwoogie would you like to share any updates on this?